# Rails 3.2.2 - has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying to refactor code to provide clean association

A GAME has a HOME_TEAM and an AWAY_TEAM

A TEAM has many GAMES as a HOME_TEAM or an AWAY_TEAM

Association between GAME and TEAM is a straight-forward HABTM BUT I need to denote which of the two TEAMS associated with a GAME is the HOME_TEAM and which is the AWAY_TEAM. I did it by adding extra fields and associations but this is obvious very wet rather than dry. I know the answer is in through but I seem to have had a brain meltdown and can't quite get my head round this.

Basically I want to be able to do Game.teams (returns collection of both teams) and Game.home_team (get and set a TEAM to home_team) and Game.away_team (get and set a TEAM to away_team)

Sorry to pose such a straightforward sounding query but it's just got away from me

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :home_team
  belongs_to :away_team
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class HomeTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_one :games
end

class AwayTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_one :games
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
  has_many :away_teams
  has_many :home_teams
end
```

All help greatly appreciated

Peter

Comment: Do you really want HomeTeam and AwayTeam to be separate classes? And, at present, separate DB tables?

Comment: No - it's just a bodge. I probably want a games_teams table with a home_team boolean I think...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what you want to do, you should use a `has_many :through` instead of `hatbm`. See [here](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off) for more info. In short, the good thing is that you can add other variables to the joins table. In your case, a boolean called home_team.

So here's what I'd do. First, create an association table (since I don't have much imagination, I'll call it participation):

```
create_table :participations, do |t|
  t.integer :game_id, :null => false
  t.integer :team_id, :null => false
  t.boolean :home_team
end
```

As you can see, unlike your gamesteams table, this one has an id. And you can add attributes to it.
Then, I would use these models:

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :team
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, :through => :participations
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :games, :through => :participations
end
```

So to get the teams of a game, you do `@game.teams`.

Now, to get home_team and away_team, add these methods to your Game model:

```
def home_team
  self.teams.joins(:participations).where("participations.home_team IS ?", true).first
end

def away_team
  self.teams.joins(:participations).where("participations.home_team IS ?", false).first
end
```

And then you'll be able to do `@game.home_team` and `@game.away_team`.

> Peter's edit: Ok, so for mysql you'll have to use different where
>   statements:
>
> self.teams.joins(:participants).where("participants.home_team = ?", true).first
>   self.teams.joins(:participants).where("participants.home_team IS NULL").first
>
> I can either use " = ?", true and "!= ?", true --OR-- IS NOT NULL and
>   IS NULL

I think for false you should try using `where("participants.home_team = ?", false)`

Ok, so so there are at least 2 ways to set up your teams.

1. You let the user pick which team is playing home
2. You assume the first team is the home team

If you go for number 1, you should use a radio button to let the user decide. Something like this:

```
<%= label_tag :home, 'Home Team' %><br />
<%= label_tag :home_team_1, 'Team 1' %><%= radio_button_tag :home_team, 1 %>
<%= label_tag :home_team_2, 'Team 2' %><%= radio_button_tag :home_team, 2 %>
```

So if `params[:home_team] == 1`, the first team is the home team, if `params[:home_team] == 2`, the second team is the home team.

If you go for number 2, then, you should have something like this in your form do add the teams to your game:

```
  <%= label_tag :name, 'Home Team' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :name => "home[]" %>

  <%= label_tag :name, 'Away Team' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :name => "away[]" %>
```

So then in your controller you can do something like

```
@game = Game.new(params[:game])

home = Team.create(params[:home])
# or
home = Team.find_or_create_by_name(params[:home][:name])
@game.participations.create(:team_id => home.id, :home_team => true or 1)

away = Team.find_or_create_by_name(params[:away][:name])
@game.participations.create(:team_id => away.id, :home_team => false or 0)
```

Comment: Ashitaka - this sounds very promising. Am building into my test bed as we speak. Will let you know if this works and accept. Thanks for your response

Comment: I edited my question and really tested it this time. It's working correctly, give it a try and tell me how it went!

Comment: Hi Ashitaka, still working through this problem. Using your solution I ran into issues with MySql and had to make a couple of changes to the where clauses

Comment: Darn - still getting used to Stack. I will put my changes at the bottom of the answer.  Last question.  What is the most objective way to set the home_team -  game.participants.first.home_team = true but this is not very technical, should I be setting something in the form I use to create the games?

Comment: There are so many way to do what you want that I don't even know where to begin :P See my edited answer

Comment: Ashitaka - all up and working. Thank you so much for all your time and effort.

Comment: Ok - will check it out and look forward to your answer

Comment: I've just put this into my form and it works without any changes to the model or controller. Again, your efforts are truly appreciated. My app is now working as hoped! Arigato (I presume)